# Unable to set partition type correctly using parted

Tags: centos, parted, bootable

I'm trying to create a bootable USB stick with FreeDos for BIOS updates in Centos 6.5, following instructions from: [chtaube.de](http://chtaube.eu/computers/freedos/bootable-usb/)

I created the empty 30MB img file using `dd`:

```
[root@dumbledore freedos_boot]# dd if=/dev/zero of=FreeDos-image.img bs=1M 
count=30
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
31457280 bytes (31 MB) copied, 0.0756911 s, 416 MB/s
```

The author of the mentioned article says this command should copy 30MB, I get 31MB. Is this a problem?

Then I use `parted` to create partitions in the resulting FreeDos-image.img file.

```
root@dumbledore freedos_boot]# parted FreeDos-image.img 
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /home/dthacker/freedos_boot/FreeDos-image.img
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit %
(parted) mklabel msdos                                                     
(parted) mkpart primary fat16 0 100%
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance. 
Ignore/Cancel? C                                                          
(parted) mkpart primary fat32 0 100%
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
(parted) set 1 boot on                                                    
(parted) p                                                                  
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/dthacker/freedos_boot/FreeDos-image.img: 100%
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End   Size  Type     File system  Flags
1      0.00%  100%  100%  primary               boot, lba
```

The File System type should be FAT16, but it's not getting set.

What do I need to do differently to set it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of those instructions on chtaube.eu :)

dd is a little bit inconsistent when it comes to sizes: `bs=1M` defines a blocksize of 1 [mebibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) meaning 1024*1024 bytes. 30 mebibytes are 30*1024*1024 = 31457280 bytes. `dd`'s final output uses the decimal megabyte with 1 MB = 1000*1000 bytes. This is why it is shown as 31 MB. So there is nothing to worry about. I've conservatively chosen the size somewhat smaller than 32 mebibytes to ensure it would fit on a USB flash drive advertised as "32 MB".

---

I just checked that issue with `parted` on Arch Linux and Debian and was able to reproduce that.

It looks like a cosmetically problem of `parted` to me, as the output of the `p` (print) command shows a "blank" file system while the partition is actually correctly created as FAT16.

You can check that with `fdisk -l FreeDos-image.img` just like I did in that typescript below:

```
ct@darkstar ~/tmp % dd if=/dev/zero of=Freedos.img bs=1M count=30
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
31457280 bytes (31 MB) copied, 0.150141 s, 210 MB/s
ct@darkstar ~/tmp % parted Freedos.img 
WARNING: You are not superuser.  Watch out for permissions.
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /home/ct/tmp/Freedos.img
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit %                                                           
(parted) mklabel msdos                                                    
(parted) mkpart primary fat16 0 100%                                      
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
Ignore/Cancel? i                                                          
(parted) set 1 boot on                                                    
(parted) p                                                                
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/ct/tmp/Freedos.img: 100%
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End   Size  Type     File system  Flags
 1      0.00%  100%  100%  primary               boot, lba

(parted) q                                                                
ct@darkstar ~/tmp % fdisk -l Freedos.img 

Disk Freedos.img: 30 MiB, 31457280 bytes, 61440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0007cae1

Device       Boot Start       End Blocks  Id System
Freedos.img1 *        1     61439  30719+  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)

ct@darkstar ~/tmp %
```

So there should be nothing wrong on your side. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out. I will take a deeper look at `parted`'s behavior and update the manual on my page accordingly.